# Webhooks with Microsoft Dynamics CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, webhooks, dynamics-crm-2015

We have started to use Microsoft CRM for all our client information however we would like to have the most up to date information from CRM for internal tools.

The way we could do this is by running a tool that looks at the data every x minutes and keeps all updated records in the database.

Could someone give a explination on how we could use webhooks for this and if it actually is possible. This would be a lot more efficient to be notified when there is a change rather than checking all the time.

I have researched and found a few projects but they were all in beta - invite only or not available.

Answer (score 1):

In Dynamics CRM Webhooks are not available as intended in the normal definition.

But you can use plugins to implement your notifications. From MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328490.aspx

> Another way to think about plug-ins is that they are handlers for
>   events fired by Microsoft Dynamics CRM. You can subscribe, or
>   register, a plug-in to a known set of events to have your code run
>   when the event occurs.

Comment: We've implemented the same as suggested, except using workflows and custom actions. This way we can also run the workflows on-demand if required